# What's the correct icon size for drawable-xxxhdpi?

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

I know all the other measures but I cant find where to see this last measure, any link or information would be appreciated...

Comment: http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/  have you looked at this?

Comment: XXXHDPI should be 192 x 192.

Comment: I mean pixelXpixel sizes

Comment: how did you look, it's the first answer on google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four times baseline of 48x48. That is 192x192 pixels.

http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: 48 * 4 = 192, not 384 ^^

Answer (score 7):

Lets consider **mdpi** as a baseline then icon size will be

- 48 × 48 (**mdpi**), 160dpi - 1x
- 72 × 72 (**hdpi**), 240dpi - 1.5x
- 96 × 96 (**xhdpi**), 320dpi - 2x
- 144 × 144 (**xxhdpi**), 490dpi - 3x
- 192 × 192 (**xxxhdpi**), 640dpi -4x
- 512 × 512 (**Google Play store**)

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 4):

- drawable-ldpi (120 dpi, Low density screen) - 36px x 36px
- drawable-mdpi (160 dpi, Medium density screen) - 48px x 48px
- drawable-hdpi (240 dpi, High density screen) - 72px x 72px
- drawable-xhdpi (320 dpi, Extra-high density screen) - 96px x 96px[image]

JellyBean Doesn't Support drawable-xxhdpi

for the xxhdpi qualifier, you will need to create an icon of the size 144*144px for your launcher icon. You can either place it in the drawable-xxhdpi or the drawable-480dpi

Answer (score 0):

The Launcher icon size for XXXHDPI should be **192 x 192** pixels

Answer (score 0):

Check [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#launcher) for size in dp:

> Launcher icons on a mobile device must be 48x48 dp.
>
> Launcher icons for display on Google Play must be 512x512 pixels.

Then lookup the conversion table in material design spec for size in pixel:
http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/units-measurements.html#units-measurements-image-scaling

Answer (score 0):

Based on Google Documentation:

xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

You can see

> http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

XXXHDPI has a [ratio of 4](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) compared to the baseline (mdpi).

Baseline being 48x48 pixels, XXHXDPI would be **192x192 pixels**.